# Using Powershell in Excel to check row status = "yes" then trigger bat file, if fail to run bat file skip and do next bat file & generate log

Tags: powershell, xlsx

I have a spreadsheet with 4 columns. so I would like to run a powershell script to check every cell in the **status** column and if yes, run the **bat file**. In the excel file there is a list of apps, their status, and a corresponding path where the bat file is stored.
If there is an error in the run of the bat file, it should skip to the next bat file and at the end generate a log file if there were errors or not for corresponding files.

#1

```
PS C:\Users\rezas> $Path = "D:\RONY\bad\list.xlsx"
Import-Excel -Path $Path

ID Application name Status bat file             
-- ---------------- ------ --------             
 1 App_1            YES    D://scripts/App_1.bat
 2 App_2            YES    D://scripts/App_2.bat
 3 App_3            YES    D://scripts/App_3.bat
 4 App_4            NO     D://scripts/App_4.bat
 5 App_5            NO     D://scripts/App_5.bat
 6
 7
 .
 .
```

#2 I can't figure out yet :(

```
  $objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$objExcel.Visible = $false
$Workbook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open(“D:\RONY\bad\list.xlsx”)
$Worksheet = $Workbook.Sheets.Item("App_list")
$UsedRange = $WorkSheet.UsedRange
$Rows = $UsedRange.Rows.Count

 $Objs = @()
 for($Row=2; $Row -le $Rows; $Row++){
     $Objs += [PSCustomObject]@{
         $ID  = $UsedRange.Cells($Row,1).Text  
         $Application_name = $UsedRange.Cells($Row,2).Text  
         $Status= $UsedRange.Cells($Row,3).Text  
         $bat_file= $UsedRange.Cells($Row,4).Text  

     }    
 }


ForEach ($ComputerName in $Objs){
if ($Status -eq 'Yes')
{
    $bat_filet
}
Else
{
    if ($Status -eq "No")
     {
        $bat_filet
     }

}
}

$objExcel.Quit()
```

Comment: Are you actually using the import-excel module and com-objects together? You will also need  `$ComputerName.Status -eq 'yes'`. If you are running into an error then please describe it. We don't know if you've tried #2 and it's not working, the output is wrong, the bat file call is wrong, it's hanging, $Rows or $Objs is empty, etc.

Comment: In the meantime I got the solution on Reddit $Path = "D:\RONY\bad\list.xlsx" $log = "D:\RONY\bad\log.txt" $objs = import-excel $Path foreach ($obj in $objs){ if ($obj.status -eq "yes"){ $batch = start-process $obj.bat -PassThru add-content $log "$((Get-Date).ToString()) Ran successfully $($obj.bat)" } }